# C implemenation of Producer-Consumer

Tags: c, pthreads

While Reading Richard Stevens' "Advanced programming in the unix environment", I tried to add a snippet of producer-consumer problem with POSIX pthread interface, but found problem implment it. Could anybody help make the following code work ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

struct msg{
    int num;
    struct msg *next;
};

struct msg *queue;

pthread_cond_t  condition = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void produce(struct msg * temp){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    temp->next = queue;
    queue = temp;
    printf("Produce: %d\n", queue->num);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    pthread_cond_signal(&condition);
}

void* consume(void * args){
    struct msg * temp;

    for(;;){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        while (queue == NULL) {
            pthread_cond_wait(&condition, &mutex);
        }
        printf("consume: %d\n", queue->num);
        temp = queue;
        queue = temp->next;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }
}

void* thread_run(void *arg){
    int i = 0;
    for(; i < 5; i++){
        struct msg m = {i + 1};
        produce(&m);
    }
}

int main(void){
    pthread_t p, consumer;

    int err = pthread_create(&p, NULL, thread_run, NULL);
    if (err != 0){
        printf("error on creating thread...\n");
    }

    err = pthread_create(&consumer, NULL, consume, NULL);
    if (err != 0){
        printf("error on creating thread...\n");
    }

    pthread_join(p, NULL);
    pthread_join(consumer, NULL);
}
```

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: The consumer thread didn't print the whole 5 correct number

Comment: We understand that this is the ultimate result. But what debugging have you done so far and what is the problem specifically?

Comment: Sorry I am new to C and with trouble debugging right now

Comment: 90% of "programming" is actually debugging so you should learn how to debug first.

Comment: "found problem". Show it.

Comment: the main problem is the consumer is locking the mutex, so the producer will sit waiting on the mutex, forever.  Suggest not locking the mutex until after the head is not  null. as a first step on solving the problem.  The consumer loop could be ignoring the head variable and be a straight line waiting on the event signal, then go into a loop consuming one struct at each loop, until head is null.

Comment: why keep executing code if a thread creation step fails?  perhaps better to exit the program.

Comment: the consume thread has no exit strategy so it will never exit, so main() will never exit,

Comment: OP needs to enable all warnings when compiling, as there are a number of problems in the code, such as a missing 'return value' statement at the end of main()

Comment: @user3629249: The consumer does not keep the mutex locked, because `pthread_cond_wait()` unlocks the mutex while it waits.